# How to do async SQL bulk insertion with pandas dataFrame.to_sql() and SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, asynchronous, sqlalchemy

I am trying to insert a bulk of data with `dataFrame.to_sql()` asynchronously. I also need to tackle the case that some data is already inside of the table (duplicates). It is a gene DB. My insertion function looks like this and is called in my router endpoint (FastAPI):

```
async def bulk_insert_genes(data_sets: pd.DataFrame):
    """Bulk insert genes from bucket to postgresDB.

    Args:
        data_sets: Dataframe of paths to the extraction datasets.
    """
    async with session_maker() as session:
        for _, row in data_sets.iterrows():
            data = generate_gene_df(row)
            conn = await session.connection()
            await conn.run_sync(
                lambda sync_conn, data=data: data.to_sql(
                    name=GenePos.__tablename__,
                    con=sync_conn,
                    if_exists="append",
                    index=False,
                    # method="multi",
                    chunksize=CHUNK_SIZE,
                    method=insert_on_duplicate,
                ),
            )
            await session.commit()
```

This is what I've found for handling duplicates on stack overflow:

```
def insert_on_duplicate(table, conn, keys, data_iter):  # noqa: ANN001
    """Insert data into table with on duplicate key update."""
    insert_stmt = insert(table.table).values(list(data_iter))
    on_duplicate_key_stmt = insert_stmt.on_duplicate_key_update(insert_stmt.inserted)
    conn.execute(on_duplicate_key_stmt)
```

The problem is, that it seems not to support async operations (`AttributeError: 'PGCompiler_asyncpg' object has no attribute 'visit_on_duplicate_key_update'`).

`generate_gene_df()` simply generates a dataFrame which fits the format of the table in the DB.

So since I am new to this topic: is there a better way to do this and how can I handle the duplicates?

Comment: Iterating over the data set and inserting each row separately is a bit of an anti-pattern in bulk inserts. You typically don't want to insert all at once, but you don't want to insert row-by-row, either, especially since the `on conflict` clause doesn't mind if you're inserting everything, a single thing, or an [*optimally-sized chunk taken into the buffer from an iterator over the source*](https://hakibenita.com/fast-load-data-python-postgresql)

Comment: @Zegarek this guide doesn't use pandas at all. Would you recommend to skip the "middle man" and directly use SQL commands instead?

Comment: @Pm740 It doesn't, but the SO thread one comment earlier does seem to address your problem. I don't know enough about what you're doing to recommend ditching `pandas` but granular control and IO performance for bulk loads have never been pandas' priority. If you want more control and more performance, the blog post above shows some examples, and you can always use [`asyncpg`](https://github.com/MagicStack/asyncpg) directly (the error suggests pandas uses it internally).

Comment: @Zegarek yeah you are probably right. I went with the answer from your first comment and it works now. Thank you :)